# How to remove single attribute with quotes via RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to match an attribute to I can do a search/replace. I am having trouble though because it is matching beyond the quotes of the attribute I want. For example, I want to remove xref="..." from here:

```
<a href="page.ashx" xref="somethingelse" title="something" class="image">
```

But when I do a RegEx like this: xref=\".*\", then it selects the attributes xref, title, AND class. How do I tell it to only select the xref attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I strongly suggest using something other than regex for modifying markup, however, this should work:

```
xref="[^"]*"
```

Comment: Sorry... Tried to remove my upvote because the coloring messed up my interpretation.  +1 again.

Comment: It depends on your source, though -- if you know it will be formatted this is fine.  If your input might be any valid HTML, a regex is really not appropriate -- it is perfectly valid HTML to have something like xref = value  (no quotes, or single quotes, or spaces around the equals sign...)

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy version: `\".*?\"`

`.*` is greedy selects as much as possible. By adding a `?` to it becomes less greedy selecting just as much as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using .net... In C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex ("xref=\"[^\"]\"\\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
regex.Replace (myHtml, "");
```