# Regex to remove attribute from xhtml document?

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
>   [How to remove single attribute with quotes via RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481320/how-to-remove-single-attribute-with-quotes-via-regex)

I am trying to remove the "sfref" attribute from the html code below:

```
<a sfref="[Libraries]719c25f9-89b3-4a7c-b6d5-e734b0c06ac1" href="../../HPLC.sflb.ashx">Determination</a> <br />
<img sfref="[Libraries]3e60aebb-acac-4806-bd22-f7986f66e7b3" src="../../Note52011.sflb.ashx">Test</a><br />
```

So far I have come up with this regex, but it is not matching:
(sfref=")([a-zA-Z0-9:;.\s()-\,]*)(")

This is where I am testing if it help:
http://regexr.com?2v4h6

Can someone please help me remove the "sfref" attribute?

Comment: The `<center>` can not hold! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I thought this looked familiar....you asked pretty much the same question in June... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481320/how-to-remove-single-attribute-with-quotes-via-regex/6481332#6481332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really really really shouldn't use regex (see the link in @Jack Maney's comment), but if you have to, this should work:

```
sfref="[^"]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for single or double quotes.

```
sfref=('|").*?\1
```