# Regex to get value of a particular attribute?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a portion of XAML string in code-behind like this

```
string str = "<Button Name = \"btn1\" Foo = \"Bar"\ /><TextBox Name=\"txtbox1\">"
```

What should be the regex to find value of only Name attributes.

I want

```
btn1
txtbox1
```

How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why don't you use an xml/html parser?

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate of a duplicate. This is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes

Comment: Here is another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481320/how-to-remove-single-attribute-with-quotes-via-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you definitely don't want to do this?

```
string str = "<Button Name = \"btn1\" /><TextBox Name=\"txtbox1\"/>";
var attrs = XElement.Parse("<r>"+str+"</r>").Elements().Attributes("Name").Select(a => a.Value);

foreach (var attr in attrs) Console.WriteLine(attr);
```

Comment: I am taking XElement from System.Xml.Linq. If that is correct then Elements().Attributes() says its an error.

Comment: You need to add a `using System.Xml.Linq` block in your code, rather than directly access `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, since `Attributes()` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<XElement>` that needs to be brought into scope. Also note I'm using `.Attributes("Name")` now after re-reading your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of LINQ, you can also use XPath to get the value.  This will get you the name of the first Button:

```
string str = "<Button Name = \"btn1\" /><TextBox Name=\"txtbox1\"/>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root>" + str + "</root>");
string name = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Button/@Name").InnerText;
```

Or, if you just want to get the first name attribute for any item:

```
string name = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/*/@Name").InnerText;
```

Or to get a list of all the name attributes for all items:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("root/*/@Name"))
{
    string name = node.InnerText';
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you can use lookaround:

```
(?<=\bName\b\s*=\s*")[^"]+
```